# Pre checking a box depending on previously chosen option by a user

Tags: jquery, ajax, database

I have an option for a user to opt out of a certain feature of my website. This stores their opt in/out decision in the DB with a "0" or "1". All that is fine, but when they visit the site again, the box is unchecked even if they have previously checked it.

I want it so when they visit the site their previous choice will be remembered. One way I thought to do this was on page load simple do an ajax request to see what value is in the database, but I am already using AJAX to save the option on click of the checkbox.

Is this too many ajax calls in one page?

Thanks.

Comment: you have to pre-populate the checkbox with the user chosen value at page load. ajax is used after the page is loaded not before.

Comment: As others have said, I'd do this at page load.  What language are you using? .NET/Java/Ruby?

Comment: Don't forget to use `.prop('checked',true)` instead of `.attr()` to mark the box.

Comment: @Blazemonger That looks like something I really should have known about - not sure why I've not come across it!  thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. You can just call it with an ajax but why would you do it in ajax, if you enter the page it needs to be set to checked from the moment you load the page right? So why make an AJAX call?

Comment: Ok yeah that makes sense, so how would you go about doing it without AJAX in that case? Just run a query in the page and set the value of the checkbox to that of the database query?

Comment: Sorry yeah thats just me being really stupid. Only recently got into the wqhole AJAX thing so its making the simplest of tasks more confusing lol. Thanks for the reply anyway, ill up yaaa

Comment: Yeah, just add something like
`code` 
<?php
$checkbox = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT checked FROM balblabl"));
if($checkbox){
   $checked = 'CHECKED';
}else{
   $checked = '';
}
?>
<input type="checkbox" <?=$checked?> />`code`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this with jQuery rather than when your page is rendered, something like this:

```
$("#<idOfCheckbox>").attr('checked', <some condition to check> ? 'checked' : null);
```

Comment: As @Blazemonger said in another comment, looks like preferred approach is to use .prop() rather than .attr().  See http://api.jquery.com/prop/ I'll leave my answer as-is though as I can't take credit for that info.